# Arabic regex matching - c++

Tags: c++, regex, arabic-support

I need to find the given string has arabic letters. It ranges from `\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F`.

I have written the below program:

```
std::vector<STD_STRING> strFieldvalues;
std::string pattern = "/[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]/";
std:string strFieldVal;
gboolArabic = false;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for ( ;i < fieldValues.size() && j< fieldNames.size(); i++,j++) //for loop its entering
{
    strFieldVal=fieldValues[i].GetPString();
    if (std::regex_match(strFieldVal, std::regex("(sub)(/[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]/)")))
    {
        gboolArabic = true;
        gArabicFieldNames.push_back(fieldNames[j].GetPString());
    }
}
```

strFieldVal is coming as <0067><062A><0627>. But its not entering into the if block.
Can anyone help .

Sample program given below is working in online compiler. In visual studio, not entering into the if block. Adding screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Comment: so `std::regex` doesn't appear to have [the best unicode support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits) if you're not using `std::wregex`. I'd highly suggest a more dedicated library like ICU, or a platform specific if you need really good unicode support.

Comment: Not sure about this, but you may need to escape `\ ` in your regex pattern string, i.e. have `\\u0600` instead of `\u0600`

Comment: or use raw string `R"(..)"`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to remove regex delimiters on both ends of the regex and apply a `+` quantifier to the regex pattern because `regex_match` requires a full string match:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string strFieldVal("المتحدة");
    std::regex pattern("[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]+");
    if (std::regex_match(strFieldVal, pattern))
    {
        std::cout << strFieldVal << " is Arabic.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/rk7tSG), output: `المتحدة is Arabic.`.

Comment: Thank you. It is working correctly in online compiler. But then i try to debug in visual studio, its not entering into the for loop. Do we need to change any project settings? Have added the screenshot with the original problem description.

Comment: @preethiselvaraju It works well in my VS 2019, see https://imgur.com/a/58htXsY and https://imgur.com/a/joRMk59. Please make sure you save your project files with Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>


int main() {
    std::wstring strFieldVal(L"المتحدة");
    std::wregex pattern(L"[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]+");
    if (std::regex_match(strFieldVal, pattern))
    {
        std::cout << strFieldVal << " is Arabic.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above one works correctly.In Visual Studio When i Add c++ source file and add this content, its asking for encoding,i given Yes. Then it worked perfectly.